# Search and replace a pattern containing backslashes

Tags: command-line, text-processing, latex

I have a file

```
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
\newcommand{\datestamp}{20180215}
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
```

I need to search for `\newcommand{\datestamp}` and want to replace a nearby pattern with a new pattern.

Required output file

```
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla                                    
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla                                                    
\newcommand{\datestamp}{20180218}                              
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla                             
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
```

The backslashes are complicating this task. How do I manage?

Comment: the dupe target doesn't make sense. `sed` is not a shell and the backslashes are not in filenames

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You likely just need to escape the backslashes i.e. `\\`

Ex.

```
$ sed '/\\newcommand{\\datestamp}/ s/{20180215}/{20180218}/' file
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
\newcommand{\datestamp}{20180218}
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
```