# find replace text in file

Tags: text-processing

I have one problem the edit info in file .php

the command I used is

```
sed -i 's/\TCG\Voyager\Models\User/Authenticatable/' "app/Models/User.php"
```

not edit segment in my shell script

other command is

```
awk '{gsub(/\TCG\Voyager\Models\User/,"Authenticatable")}1' "app/Models/User.php"
```

the segment of text is `"\TCG\Voyager\Models\User"` in my file not is one route

find file is

```
"class User extends \TCG\Voyager\Models\User"
```

remplace for

```
"class User extends Authenticatable"
```

Comment: just replace backslashes with another backslash `\\TCG\\Voyager\\Models\\User`; https://askubuntu.com/q/1013419/283843

Comment: thanks is the solution

Comment: [answer] sed -i 's/\\TCG\\Voyager\\Models\\User/Authenticatable/' "app/Models/User.php"

Comment: CarlosCardenas or @αғsнιη it would be great if you could post the solution as an answer so the question can be marked as answered.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search and replace a pattern containing backslashes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013419/search-and-replace-a-pattern-containing-backslashes)